# How to retrieve data from string in php?

Tags: php, arrays, html, arraylist, checkbox

i have an array like this one : Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday,. Now i would like to have each day separately and for each one i need need to add a checkbox near it .Thank you for help.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you**

Comment: Have you any code that you have tried to do this with

Comment: What Have You Tried From Your End? Please Paste Your Tried Code.

Comment: i'm new with php , i have a string in my html page and i need to get each day and add checkbox to it

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="role"><?= $this->translate("Days") ?> <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                        <?=$value["days"]?>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the days as an array to be able to loop through them with a foreach loop.

```
<?php
$days = array(
    'Monday',
    'Tuesday',
    'Wednesday',
    'Thursday',
    'Friday',
    'Saturday',
    'Sunday'
);

foreach($days as $day) {
    echo $day;
    echo '<input type="checkbox">';
}
?>
```

**Update:**

As you have stored your days as a string, you will need to explode the string to convert this to an array so that you can loop through them.

```
<?php
$days = "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thurday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday";
$days = explode(", ", $days);

foreach($days as $day) {
    echo $day;
    echo '<input type="checkbox">';
}
?>
```

Comment: my string is like this : Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, so need to retrieve each day and echo it

Comment: @samersboui And that is what the code does. The only difference is that heady has sunday in the array. EDIT; I see string...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
    $days=array("Sunday", "Monday", ... );
    foreach($days as $day){
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="day" value="'.$day.'">'.$day.'<br>';
    }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: i have a string not an array !!

Comment: @samersboui DUDE!!! Chill! I quote you: `i have an array of week days like this one` Let me make my point clear "i have an **array** of week days like this one"

Comment: @Andreas i sent a string to my view and i would like to retrieve days from it

Comment: @samersboui : you have written in your question that you have an array.

Comment: @samersboui : also if you have a string then you can convert that string into an array, and then follow the same step. you can use explode function to convert a string to array.

Comment: @samersboui : your welcome. if you got the anser then please make green tick on my answer. thanks